# TypeScript - 'Unexpected token' for async function prefix

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, asynchronous, async-await

I'm receiving an 'Unexpected token' error in typescript where I'm trying to write an async function like this:

```
async function test() {
  ...
}
```

I've seen that this can be caused due to running an older version of node that doesn't support async function syntax, but mine was running version 8.

Just to remove any possibility of my node version not supporting this, I've just updated to version 9.11.1, checked that this is being used in the command line, and the async prefix is still returning the unexpected token error.

Comment: could you check the typescript version ?

Comment: Does it work when you remove the async token? Are you writing your program in Notepad? If so, try converting the EOL char. I had problems with node seeing it as illegal

Comment: did you try write this way : `async test(){}` ?

Comment: @fatemefazli Looks like that's fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: Apparently, according to the [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function), the `async function test() { }` syntax should be perfectly valid, though

Comment: @JeremyThille only if it's .js but in .ts remove the function tag

Comment: What's the context of the code? Is this a top level function or a function declaration within the body of a class or object literal?

Answer (score 3):

[That syntax is fine](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/IYZwngdgxgBAZgV2gFwJYHsL3egFAShgG8AoGcmZACwCd0B3GCAU0YFEa6bcByAKQQhkMYFmYAPYAFsADgBtmPfAG4SAXxJA):

```
async function foo() {
    throw new Error('Just an example');
}
```

...but if you're trying to use it in a context where the `function` keyword is invalid, it won't compile, and it's not even valid JavaScript. For example, these are not valid:

```
class Foo {
  async function foo() {
    // Syntax error!
  }
}
```

```
const blah = {
  async function foo() {
    // Syntax error!
  }
}
```

`async function` used in this way is fine for declaring a function but not for defining methods. For methods, you'll want to omit the `function` keyword:

```
class Foo {
  async foo() {
  }
}
```

```
const blah = {
  async foo() {
  }
}
```

...or use a function expression:

```
const blah = {
  foo: async function () {
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer goes into more detail than mine about why it doesn't work. +1

Answer (score 1):

Still running into this as of Node 12.16.3

The solution is to remove the `function` tag and use the following syntax:

```
async test() {
  // Function body
}
```

Comment: Funnily enough I was getting the exact same error because I did not have the `function` tag. Adding it fixed the error